# How to properly lazy load components in React when using Auth0?

Tags: reactjs, security, authentication, auth0

I've implemented Auth0 to my react front-end and would like to lazy load components.
I'm not sure what the correct setup should be to verify a user is logged in prior to loading the hidden components?

I've come up with this simple example of how I think it would work, however I'm not entirely sure.

I'm not very good with security principles yet. What would stop someone from being able to flip the value of isAuthenticated to true using devtools? If there's a resource that you believe would be great to learn this, I would appreciate it very much too!

Example of the way I believe it would be implemented:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import NotAuthenticatedError from "./NotAuthenticatedError";
const MyLazyLoadedComponent = lazy(() => import(...));


export default function App() {

const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {isAuthenticated && (
        <Suspense fallback={<NotAuthenticatedError />}>
       
         <MyLazyLoadedComponent / >
        

        </Suspense>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is why we should always have the user validations in backend. So that event if someone managed to see your Authenticated Components, if he tries to perform some actions, the backend still verifies that the user is authorized or not. In case of auth0 you can send the access token in headers to backed in every request, and then validate the token in backend with auth0. Thus you can be sure that only an authorized user is making the requests

Comment: Thanks so much for the input! I did setup Auth0 protection on my backend as well! Every request requires a token which will get validated on the server side! I'm mostly just curious on the best practices for protecting the client side!